# Xcode archiving build

Tags: xcode, bash

Here is my script

```
# Type a script or drag a script file from your workspace to insert its path.
# skip if we run in debug
if [ "$CONFIGURATION" == "Debug" ]; then
    echo "Skip frameworks cleaning in debug version"
    exit 0
fi

APP_PATH="${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${WRAPPER_NAME}"

# This script loops through the frameworks embedded in the application and
# removes unused architectures.
find "$APP_PATH" -name '*.framework' -type d | while read -r FRAMEWORK
do
    FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_NAME=$(defaults read "$FRAMEWORK/Info.plist" CFBundleExecutable)
    FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH="$FRAMEWORK/$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_NAME"
    echo "Executable is $FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"

    # Check if the framework executable path exists
    if [ ! -f "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH" ]; then
        echo "Error: $FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH does not exist."
        continue
    fi

    # Extract the architectures for each framework
    for ARCH in $ARCHS
    do
        echo "Extracting $ARCH from $FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_NAME"
        # Check if the input file is a fat file
        lipo "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH" -verify_arch "$ARCH"
        if [ $? != 0 ]; then
            echo "Error: $FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH is not a fat file."
            continue
        fi
        # Extract the architecture
        lipo -extract "$ARCH" "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH" -o "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-$ARCH"
        if [ $? != 0 ]; then
            echo "Error: Failed to extract $ARCH from $FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_NAME"
            continue
        fi
    done

    # Merge extracted architectures
    echo "Merging extracted architectures: ${ARCHS}"
    lipo -o "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-merged" -create "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-$ARCHS"
    if [ $? != 0 ]; then
        echo "Error: Failed to merge architectures for $FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_NAME"
        continue
    fi

    # Replace original executable with thinned version
    echo "Replacing original executable with thinned version"
    rm "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"
    mv "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-merged" "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"

    # Clean up extracted architecture files
    rm "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-$ARCHS"
done
```

Errors while archiving

```
Asset validation failed
Invalid MinimumOSVersion. Apps that only support 64-bit devices must specify a deployment target of 8.0 or later. MinimumOSVersion in 'On Showtime.app/Frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework' is ''. (ID: 3d746089-deb8-4b15-ab50-e0e60c0170c7)

Asset validation failed
Invalid MinimumOSVersion. Apps that only support 64-bit devices must specify a deployment target of 8.0 or later. MinimumOSVersion in 'On Showtime.app/Frameworks/GoogleAppMeasurement.framework' is ''. (ID: ab047bc6-0bc3-4c60-9d3e-027ba423816b)

Asset validation failed
Invalid MinimumOSVersion. Apps that only support 64-bit devices must specify a deployment target of 8.0 or later. MinimumOSVersion in 'On Showtime.app/Frameworks/GoogleAppMeasurementIdentitySupport.framework' is ''. (ID: af1717c7-7936-4cca-8aec-a3d281bfdceb)

Asset validation failed
Missing Info.plist value. A value for the key 'MinimumOSVersion' in bundle On Showtime.app/Frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework is required. (ID: 5751780f-a23f-4793-aa2f-f7d30c14dd02)

Asset validation failed
Missing Info.plist value. A value for the key 'MinimumOSVersion' in bundle On Showtime.app/Frameworks/GoogleAppMeasurement.framework is required. (ID: 25757f18-808d-448c-8141-3853c3de8892)

Asset validation failed
Missing Info.plist value. A value for the key 'MinimumOSVersion' in bundle On Showtime.app/Frameworks/GoogleAppMeasurementIdentitySupport.framework is required. (ID: 5e9475fe-1f81-41a2-bb2c-fc0eafae8528)

Asset validation failed
The bundle 'Payload/On Showtime.app/Frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework' is missing plist key. The Info.plist file is missing the required key: CFBundleShortVersionString. Please find more information about CFBundleShortVersionString at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/cfbundleshortversionstring (ID: 9730fdb9-e283-4228-997d-59821153228c)

Asset validation failed
The bundle 'Payload/On Showtime.app/Frameworks/GoogleAppMeasurement.framework' is missing plist key. The Info.plist file is missing the required key: CFBundleShortVersionString. Please find more information about CFBundleShortVersionString at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/cfbundleshortversionstring (ID: 1c5a66f1-f09e-4ea6-9858-047d5ab9dcb7)

Asset validation failed
The bundle 'Payload/On Showtime.app/Frameworks/GoogleAppMeasurementIdentitySupport.framework' is missing plist key. The Info.plist file is missing the required key: CFBundleShortVersionString. Please find more information about CFBundleShortVersionString at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/cfbundleshortversionstring (ID: caddb847-0028-4dab-b19e-8fe17e6f22c5)

Asset validation failed
Invalid Bundle. The bundle On Showtime.app/Frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework does not support the minimum OS Version specified in the Info.plist. (ID: 16992502-8efc-4833-aa12-7ab643d955c8)

Asset validation failed
Invalid Bundle. The bundle On Showtime.app/Frameworks/GoogleAppMeasurement.framework does not support the minimum OS Version specified in the Info.plist. (ID: b74472a1-2580-4272-8da6-ef0c6e0918cd)

Asset validation failed
Invalid Bundle. The bundle On Showtime.app/Frameworks/GoogleAppMeasurementIdentitySupport.framework does not support the minimum OS Version specified in the Info.plist. (ID: 86cc2f3c-a0ab-45dd-a64e-f4d6714c725b)
```